# Gnome 3.2 problems in the shell

Tags: 11.10, ati, gnome

Does anyone experienced some problems in gnome 3.2 environment, like problems in the shell?

[image]

How can i fix it?

I have made a test, if there was some problem on graphics, but everything seems fine:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the latest ATI 11.10 drivers, people are reporting that updating their driver solves the problem for them.

You will need to remove all the current fglrx packages from your system and download the driver from the ATI site.

Remove the fglrx drivers if you installed them

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

Download the newest ATI driver (current version is 11.12)

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

**If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once downloaded go to the file location and set it to run as executable

```
cd /path_of_the_file
chmod 755 ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
```

Create the packages and install them on your system

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once the driver is installed you need to start up a new xorg.conf file with this command

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: this process can improve unity performance too?

Comment: another thing, how can I make sure that ubuntu is using fglrx driver instead of vesa driver?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_know_fglrx_is_installed_correctly.3F), there are several methods, if something goes wrong post a question on the site for further assistance.

Comment: This didn't work for me... I'm getting all sorts of error messages...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99662/ati-11-12-driver-help   I have created another question regarding my issue...

Comment: @Jordan - I agree with Bruno - Can I suggest you flag this to get your Bounty back.  Then you will be able to re-bounty if you dont get an answer for your own question in the interim.  Remember in your own question, add as much detail about your graphics card and driver as possible.

Comment: For updating to the latest ATI drivers (post-updates) see http://askubuntu.com/questions/78906/ati-amd-proprietary-fglrx-graphics-install-fails-how-can-i-resolve-the-problem/97564#97564

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a few months ago. It looked exactly like that and did some other stuff. It looked like this:

[image: distorted image]

It was the graphics driver I had installed. Just navigate to `Settings`->`Additional Drivers` and uninstall them. If it doesn't work, log in to Ubuntu and uninstall them there. Then reboot. It worked for me! Hope this helps