# What version of the Catalyst driver ships with 11.10?

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

Hello i wonder if Ubuntu is using the new 11.10 driver. or do i have to install it manually from AMD's site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at the moment, latest package is 11.9. You need to download it and manually install it. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73615/gnome-3-2-problems-in-the-shell/74886#74886) shows you what to do.

Comment: mark it complete plz if you the answer on the other question installed the drivers for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this guide when installing the latest ATI drivers he keeps up on the latest fglrx and has been around since 5.04 or so

here is the link

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29