# How can I see what version of AMD catalyst is in the "Additional Drivers"

Tags: ati

How can I see what version of AMD catalyst is in the "Additional Drivers"?
I know that now it's 11.8, but it does not work with my HD 6320 graphics chip in the AMD E-450 APU.
It is not possible to see what version is in the "Additional Drivers" before installing it.
It seems that Catalyst 11.10 has better support for 6320, but how do i find out when it will be in Ubuntu Repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What version of the Catalyst driver ships with 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75076/what-version-of-the-catalyst-driver-ships-with-11-10)

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Software Center, then search for fglrx and choose Binary ATI-Xorg driver (more information button). Here you can see, which version is shipped with Ubuntu.

I do not recommend to install the proprietary driver on AMD Fusion E-350/450 platform, because bad performance in flash and other videos (my experience).

If you want to install latest catalyst drivers, follow this step-by-step instructions:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

To have a better Flash performance on low end CPUs copy&paste this command in a terminal window:

sudo mkdir /etc/adobe && echo "OverrideGPUValidation=true"|sudo tee /etc/adobe/mms.cfg

Comment: I tried the new Catalyst 11.10, it was much faster than the version  in the repositories and the open source driver. But i think that unity could not use it in 3D only 2D (i think, how do i tell?) What can i do?