# HD Videos are laggy with Mobility HD 4250 in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, ati

I have an Mobility HD 4250 graphics on my computer. Im trying to watch HD videos 1080p from YouTube, but when watching them, they are very laggy. I have proprietary drivers. I have disabled Sync to VBlank and Detect freshrate from CCSM, and my Ubuntu works fine with those settings, but HD video lag is the only problem with this. When i had Windows, i was able to watch 1080p videos smoothly. Possible to fix this? I use Chrome and i have installed Flash when i installed 11.10.

Comment: How do normal HD 1080p movies run on your Ubuntu? Not in the browser, but simply playing them. If the movie plays correctly, then your problem lies at the internet connection. Playing 1080p on the web can strain up your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I do the process explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74886/40354), and got a little better performance.

Anyway, ATI driver still suck.

Answer (score 0):

Just type "VLC" in Ubuntu Software Center to download VLC Media Player.

This multimedia player will enhance bitrate and HD video runs in FLOW.